# Filter words in Database row, and count them

Tags: php, mysql, database, woocommerce, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to count how many times the word "ItzBenji" is listed in the database

[image]

But i have no clue what so ever, on how to do it :(

It's a woocommerce table, of "order_items" and i want to count how many times the specific Coupon code is used. How can i do that I tried this i found online:

```
$sql = "select * from wp_woocommerce_order_items"; //Select All
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    if($row['order_item_name'] == itzbenji) 
    {
         echo "test";
    }
}
```

But that did not work :(

How to do it? And make it echo a number like "It is used 3 times"

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(order_item_name) AS rowcount
FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items
WHERE order_item_name = 'itzbenji'
```

Then in your PHP, just `echo $row['rowcount'];`

Comment: Okay, but just a stupid rookie question: How do i fix this error? IM totally new to php. https://gyazo.com/4b280ea550aa013783910d0b70cb02b4

Comment: Okay so im getting thsi in the phpadmin: https://gyazo.com/d022c0fdf0aab44bc59fc395b8ea3710 But nothing when i try to echo it out? - https://gyazo.com/7b9ddc804cc82365abcfaa1fb9036b92 The page is just blank?

Answer (score -2):

You could use sql to get this done.

```
$sql = "select COUNT(order_item_name)" + 
       "from wp_woocommerce_order_items" + 
       "where order_item_name = 'ItzBenji'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "Its used " + $result + "times"
```

Anyone feel free to correct me on this one.